# File Path in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, file, path

I do have a requirement to execute a PowerShell script from command line to retrieve file information.
The folder and files are located on a  shared server. I do have a script which gives me that info as below
But the biggest issue is how and where do i define the server path file location in the below script.
Currently if i execute this script in command prompt from c: it will give the info from that drive and so on

```
$shell = New-Object -com shell.application
  gci | select Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,
     @{N='Author';E={$shell.NameSpace(($_.DirectoryName)).ParseName(($_.Name)).ExtendedProperty("System.Author")}},
     @{N='Owner';E={ If ($_.PSIsContainer) {
         $Shell.NameSpace(($_.FullName)).Self.ExtendedProperty("System.FileOwner")
      } Else {
          $shell.NameSpace(($_.DirectoryName)).ParseName(($_.Name)).ExtendedProperty("System.FileOwner")
     }}}
```

Tried:

```
$shell = New-Object -com shell.application
  gci | select Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,
     @{N='Author';E={$shell.NameSpace(($_.DirectoryName)).ParseName(($_.Name)).ExtendedProperty("System.Author")}},
     @{N='Owner';E={ If ($_.PSIsContainer) {
         $Shell.NameSpace(($_.FullName)).Self.ExtendedProperty("System.FileOwner")
      } Else {
          $shell.NameSpace(($_.DirectoryName)).ParseName(($_.Name)).ExtendedProperty("System.FileOwner")
     }}}
```

Need a solution to define file path

Comment: put the initial path after `gci` (`Get-ChildItem`)...

Comment: I tried changing as per your advice but it did not work, Can you pls advice more on this

Comment: I tried changing as per your advice but it did not work, Can you pls advice more on this   $imptext = "\\rigfpt06\Shared\Results\"
>> $shell = New-Object -com shell.application
>>      gci (Get-ChildItem)-$imptext| select Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,
>>      @{N='Author';E= ............

Comment: Please read about [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and learn how to specify the path for it to search in. There are more parameters you can use to have it search for files only, directories only or both, recurse through subfolders or not, filter for a specific name or extension etc..

Comment: Thanks Theo, Do you have a example or a link to share.